# WSO2 DAS: certificate didn't match

Tags: wso2, iot, wso2-das

I'm installed `WSO2 DAS Server` on my LAN network, but I can't create new `Dashboard` because this error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: 
>   <192.168.3.27> != localhost

in [log file here](http://pastebin.com/4Z6YxgY2).

Please help and thanks

Answer (score 1):

It  happens due to certificate is for localhost not for the domain that we run. For that we need to generate new certificate with specific domain and configuration changes with correct .jks file and correct password.

It will resolve the certificate didn't match. We need to replace all the localhost in the portal folder. If  I have worked like these and fixed with gaudiness. For more refernce please visit 
http://www.vitharana.org/2012/12/how-to-add-new-keystore-to-carbon-4_3.html

Answer (score -1):

Above error log happens due to certificate is for localhost not for the host (192.168.3.27). You can fix this by importing KeyStore file to the trustore by using following commands in the terminal.

```
keytool -export -alias <HostName> -file mycert.crt -keystore myjks.jks -storepass <pwd>

keytool -import -alias <HostName> -file /usr/local/app/wso2/wso2das-3.0.0/repository/resources/security/mycert.crt -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Please refer following articles for more details [1]. On the other hand for a quick test you can access dashboard portal in http by using following URL

```
http://localhost:9763/portal/
```

[1] https://medium.com/@dunithd/wso2-das-how-to-fix-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-160c13bc8fe7#.npua5d4nf